# Problem with date/time setting

Tags: date, config, date-format, entry-date, edit-date

So I have ExpressionEngine Core Core v2.10.1 - Build Date: 20150501 installed and under localisation I have set to see 24 hour default time formatting and to include seconds in the default time format, but when I go to list of entries, that setting is not applied. I still see AM/PM time and also when I go in the entry and want to change time of publishing for some entry I get an error: "This form has expired. Please refresh and try again."
I did put in config.php $config['disable_csrf_protection'] = "y"; but it did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the date formatting options for your members (in this case, I suppose, the Superadmin) as well.

Comment: that was it. I forgot about it. For me that is really stupid solution, if I as admin change some setting, I should be able to save that setting to all users or at least to be warned about possible differences.

Comment: Isn't there an option that prohibits users from using such custom formatting options? That might work. Either way, glad you're up and running.

Comment: A second thought, I'm not sure how EE Core (i.e., without the Member module) compares to the full version.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the localization preferences for all members by setting the following config variable:

```
$config['allow_member_localization'] = 'n';
```

EE will then use the fallback include_seconds config variable. I had a similar issue and added the following code to my config.php to solve it:

```
$config['include_seconds'] = 'y';
$config['allow_member_localization'] = 'n';
```